# Docker on startup: "No activity detected on VM, aborting"

Tags: windows, docker, vmware

I have downloaded and installed latest version of Docker (inside a VMWare VM, win 10 Enterprise). I get the follwing error. Upon googling on this I just get a lot of cases referring to another thread (that doesnt have a solution either), some threads just die out.

Please No references, If you know what the problem is just write it here on SO :)

> **No activity detected on VM, aborting**    at
>   Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[]
>   parameters) in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:line
>   36    at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx,
>   Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line
>   92    at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.b__0()
>   in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line
>   155    at Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:line 59

futher information in log file

> [NamedPipeServer][Error  ] Unable to execute Start: No activity
>   detected on VM, aborting    at
>   Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings, String
>   daemonOptions) in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line
>   268    at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings
>   settings, String daemonOptions) in
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line
>   117

(I have only one CPU on my VM, after another tip. )

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... maybe _I confused multiple processors with multiple cores when I said Ive already tested one CPU:s

When you have multiple cores (in my VM settings) it doesnt work. But when I have 1 core, it works, both with 1 and multiple CPUs.

It might have taken more than one restart or that you should do things in the right order...anyway: It have been working ok for a few says now so I guess you should not have multiple cores when you run on a VM

If you have this problem and changing to 1 core helps you, please write a quick comment on this post, to help others. Im not sure if it was this that made the trick

Comment: For me it is noto working - when docker is switching to linux containers it reverts my changes back (from on eprocessor back to two processors, max 4)

Answer (score 0):

I have 4 CPUs set in Docker/setting/advanced, but my hard disk is slow. When I start my Docker, my disk activity time is 100%, then I can see "No activity detected on VM, aborting". But my disk activity time is still 100%. So I wait for a time, when activity time is 0%, I restart the Docker and my Docker is running.